# Elegant transformation between an IEnumerable<object[]> and an IEnumerable<object>[]

Tags: c#, arrays, iterator, enumerable

Is there any way to transform an `IEnumerable<int[]>` to `IEnumerable<int>[]` ? Concretely I have a following IEnumerable:

```
    IEnumerable<int[]> data = new List<int[]>()
    {
    new int[]{1,11},
    new int[]{2,22},
    new int[]{3,33},
    new int[]{4,44},
    // ...
    // ...
    };
```

and I want to turn it into the following shape:

```
    IEnumerable<int>[] data = new List<int>[] 
    { 
    new List<int>(){1,2,3,4 },
    new List<int>(){11,22,33,44}
    };
```

The only solution I have so far come up with goes as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<int>[] Convert(IEnumerable<int[]> data)
{
    var length = data.First().Length;
    var output = new List<int>[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)   
        output[i] = new List<int>();
    foreach (var entry in data) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)    
        {
            output[i].Add(entry[i]);
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

This though isn't ideal, as I need to iterate over the whole data set. Desired solution would be making use of LINQ or built-in iterator pattern features (`yield return`). Is there any better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind the multiple enumerations of `data`, you can do this:

```
public static IEnumerable<int>[] Convert(IEnumerable<int[]> data)
{
    var length = data.First().Length;
    var output = new IEnumerable<int>[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        output[i] = CustomEnumerable(i);
    }

    return output;

    IEnumerable<int> CustomEnumerable(int index)
    {
        foreach (var entry in data) 
        {
            yield return entry[index];
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, instead of populating lists, I'm returning custom `IEnumerable<int>`s, which are created with a local iterator function (using `yield return`).

If you care about iterating `data` only once, you could do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<int>[] Convert(IEnumerable<int[]> data)
{
    var found = new List<int[]>();
    using var enumerator = data.GetEnumerator();
    var proxy = ProxyEnumerable();
    
    var length = proxy.First().Length;
    var output = new IEnumerable<int>[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        output[i] = CustomEnumerable(i);
    }

    return output;

    IEnumerable<int> CustomEnumerable(int index)
    {
        foreach (var entry in proxy) 
        {
            yield return entry[index];
        }
    }
    
    IEnumerable<int[]> ProxyEnumerable()
    {    
        foreach (var value in found)
        {
            yield return value;
        }

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var value = enumerator.Current;
            found.Add(value);
            yield return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here I added another `IEnumerable<int[]>` that is filling a cache `List<int[]>` as we iterate over it. So that `data` is iterated only once, and subsequent iteration use the cache.

[Try it online](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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).

Comment: The second proposed solution is exactly what I craved for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have hier one short sugestion with LINQ. With the example below you can get a jagged array

```
var maxLength = data.Max(x => x.Length);
var converted = new IEnumerable<int>[maxLength]
    .Select((dst, index) => data
        .Select(src => src.Length > index ? src[index] : default)
        .Where(n => n != default));
```

and with this you can cut your source array into matrix

```
var minLength = data.Min(x => x.Length);
var converted = new IEnumerable<int>[minLength]
    .Select((dst, index) => data
        .Select(src => src[index]));
```